# q-exponential functions

Tags: limits, special-functions, factorial, q-series, q-analogs

We know that 
$$e_q(z)=\sum_{j\geq 0} \frac{z^j}{(q;q)_j}=\frac{1}{(z;q)_{\infty}}$$

where $(a;q)_{\infty}=\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}(1−aq^i)$ denotes the q-shifted factorial.

The limit between the $q$-exponential and the ordinary exponential is

$$\lim_{q\rightarrow1}e_q((1-q)z)=\lim_{q\rightarrow1}\frac{1}{((1-q)z;q)_{\infty}}=e^z.$$

My question is how to prove

$$\lim_{q\rightarrow1}\frac{1}{((1-q)\sqrt{1-q^2}x;q)_{\infty}}=e^{\sqrt{2}x}?$$

I'm glad for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $(q;q)_n=(1-q)^n[n]_q!\;$ and $\lim_{q\to1} [n]_q!=n!.\quad$ Therefore $$e_q((1-q)(1+q)x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1-q)^n(1+q)^nx^n}{(q;q)_n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1+q)^n x^n}{[n]_q!}.$$
The limit as $q\to1$ gives $e^{2x}$ which is justified because of absolute convergence.

Comment: Mr @Somos Can we permute the limit and the sum ?

Comment: @othmane Yes, go ahead. See what you get and let us know.

Comment: Mr @somos it's my bad i forgot a number,  in fact this is my question

Comment: Mr@somos it's my bad i forgot a number, in fact this is my question                  $$\lim_{q\rightarrow 1} e_q((1-q)\sqrt{1-q}(1+q)x) $$

Comment: @othmane I didn't understand your comment at first. Please see this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296429/moving-a-limit-inside-an-infinite-sum).

Comment: The problem is in the limit,  i have edited my question  above .

Comment: @othmane Are you sure you want $((1-q)\sqrt{1-q^2}x;q)_{\infty}$? I did some computation and I think you want $((1-q)\sqrt{1+q}x;q)_{\infty}$ to get the $e^{\sqrt{2}x}$ result. Please try a numerical example to check your limit.